# After fresh install of Anaconda and PyCharm console won't connect with DLL load failure

Tags: python, installation, pycharm, anaconda

I installed the latest version of Anaconda (2018.12) with Python 3.7 and the pro version of Pycharm (2018.3). When I try to open a project I get the following error `ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.` and the console won't connect.

Comment: It is a known problem https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-27234. First step in the answer below should resolve the issue in the most cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the steps below.

**1. Start pycharm.exe or pycharm64.exe from Anaconda prompt**

Open Anaconda prompt and simply paste the full path to pycharm.exe and confirm with Enter.

Alternatively, create a "PyCharm.bat" file and paste and adjust the following code:

```
set CondaDir="C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3"
set PyCharm="C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.3.2\bin\pycharm64.exe"
call %CondaDir:"=%\Scripts\activate.bat
%PyCharm%
```

**2. Check that the python interpreter is set correctly**

Go to the menu File > Settings > Project: ... > Project Interpreter. Then click on the gear icon and Show All ... Here you can set a virtual environment or system interpreter.

**3. Check Working Dir**

Go to the menu File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Console > Python Console > Working Directory. Make sure the Working Directory exists and that you have read / wright privileges.

**4. Update packages and Anaconda**

Update all packages with `conda update --all`

Update conda with `conda update conda`

**5. Reinstall Anaconda and Pycharm**

Do this if nothing else helps.

Comment: Create the "PyCharm.bat" File where?

Comment: @SanchitBhatnagar The location shouldn’t matter.